# How to automatically reload page after a certain time based on a php variable

Tags: php, javascript

I currently have a php file that automatically plays the song at the top of a playlist. I have a `$duration` value that I pull from a mysql database and I want the page to automatically refresh after the song is finished playing.

The song is currently played within an iframe so this is the only way to tell that the song has approximately finished.

I've tried doing this in javascript but I'm having issues trying to pass a variable to the timeout period.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod{
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    }
</script>

<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh($x);">
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/lesser-known-facts-about-html/

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a straightforward PHP variable output into the source:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod){
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",<?php echo $song_duration_in_milliseconds; ?>);
}
</script>
```

Or use meta-refresh as pointed out in @Matt Clark's answer.

Comment: There's no need for the function parameter with this solution.

Comment: @sachleen That is correct. I was just keeping it within the framework of OP's existing code.  You could just as easily lose the entire function altogether and just do `setTimeout`

Comment: Fair enough. And that's what I would do, since you would probably never call the function at a later/specific time.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a META tag for refresh.

**In PHP:**

```
<?php
    $Refresh = 600;
?>
```

And in your HTML head you can modify a META Tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?= $Refresh ?>">
```

Or as stated by Amadan you can just use the PHP to specify the meta tag in your PHP:

```
header("Refresh: " . $Refresh);
```

**Or In Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",<?= $Refresh ?>);
</script>
```

**Side Notes**

The short tags:

```
<?= $Variable, $Variable2 ?>
```

Are the equivalent of using:

```
<?php echo $Variable; echo $Variable2; ?>
```

Comment: If it's PHP, might as well send the `Refresh` header. [`meta`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks) just emulates it for cases where manipulation of headers is not possible.

Comment: Note that the short tag `<?=` is not always allowed by php config, although after 5.4.0 it should always be available.